# How to build osm tileserver (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)?

Tags: openstreetmap, ubuntu, osm2pgsql, tile-server

I'm trying to follow the tutorial: 
https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/

And the first part works greatly, but because i'm new at using Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit) i'm stuck at my first ERROR:

```
**Installing osm2pgsql**

osm2pgsql is under active development and is best compiled from source.

    mkdir ~/src
    cd ~/src 
    git clone git://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql.git
    cd osm2pgsql
    ./autogen.sh

*bash: ./autogen.sh: No such file or directory*
```

so the next lines won't work at all:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

I also tried the tutorial on github: 
git://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql.git

I'm a complete novice according to Linux, so if someone can explain me, or if there is someone with a other (working) tutorial, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Check the readme file of osm2pgsql

first install dependencies as mentioned in readme file, if you follow the switch2osm guide, then you have probably installed them in the beginning

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: osm2pgsql recently switched to cmake, i.e. the current documentation on switch2osm.org on how to compile osm2pgsql is a bit outdated...

Comment: The documentation needs update,  their advice to apt-get install node-carto was wrong for me because I have newer node.js than the one in repositories. If it bites you, too, just install node-carto using npm instead of apt-get. I also followed instructions from postgresql site to install it along with postgis and creating a tablespace. A new section also about updating the db with diffs should be added. And how about documentation about "Building manual tile server on Centso 7". That's a challenge...